# Compound formula without decimals

Tags: solidity

I am programming in Solidity and trying to write a formula to calculate a compounding amount, I can write the formula in something like Excel as:

```
1 * (1 + 0.0025) ^ 2212
```

However, this obviously doesn't work is Solidity, so I tried;

```
uint rate = 25;
return 1 * (1 + (rate / 10000)) ** 2212;
```

Which still doesn't work.. *explanation in edit below.*

Anyone have some guidance on how I can get this working?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** by doesn't work, I mean that Solidity does not support floating point numbers in any form, 25/10000 returns 0 (not 0.0025). Which then results in the whole equation returning 1 (the real answer is 250).

My assumption is that the only way I can really do this is by re-working this equation into something that doesn't involve decimals places (or very large numbers, because raising to-the-power-of quickly gets out of hand).

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work"

Comment: @daltonclaybrook See my edit above for further explanation.